# sql server, update table A if table A record exists in table B

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table structure. .

```
Table A
a_ID | status
-------------
 1       BAD
 2       OK
 3       OK
 4       BAD
 5       BAD

TABLE B
b_ID | a_ID
-------------
 1       1
 2       4
```

After update query . .

```
Table A
a_ID | status
-------------
 1       OK
 2       OK
 3       OK
 4       OK
 5       BAD
```

I hope you get the idea.
Please help.

Edit: I tried

```
UPDATE TABLE_A set status = 'OK' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE_B)
```

.. but all rows were affected. .

Comment: Add the SQL you've tried to your question, working or not.

Comment: Hint, you can use joins in an update statement.

Comment: You're not stating what in the exists you want to look at.  The way you've written this is like saying WHERE 1=1.  To work correctly you'd need to write it like this:  UPDATE TABLE_A A set status = 'OK' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE_B B where A.[a_ID] = B.[a_ID])

Comment: Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the ID a_ID is kind of redundant

```
update a 
set a.status = 'OK' 
from a 
join b 
  on a.id = b.id 
 and a.status <> 'OK'
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This one is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Join to update your table as below.

```
UPDATE [LenqReloaded].[dbo].A SET [ResponseLetterSent] = 1 
FROM [LenqReloaded].[dbo]. A 
join [LenqReloaded].[dbo]. B on A.[a_ID] = B.[a_ID] 
WHERE A.[ResponseLetterSent] IS NULL
```